# org.json.JSONException in android studio

Tags: android, json, android-volley

im trying to get json from openweathermap.com using volley 
i have this java code :

```
 public void findWeather(int latitude,int longitude){
    final Info info=new Info();
    url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat="+latitude+"&lon="+longitude+"&appid=9a40ef2a4c35689b29978690445e03e0&units=metric";
    final JsonObjectRequest objectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
               JSONArray jsonArray=response.getJSONArray("list");
                JSONObject jsonObjectMain=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("main");
               JSONObject jsonObjectWeather=jsonArray.getJSONArray(2).getJSONObject(0);
                JSONObject jsonObjectWind=jsonArray.getJSONObject(5);
                String date=jsonArray.getString(6);
            info.setTemp(jsonObjectMain.getString("temp"));
            info.setDescription(jsonObjectWeather.getString("description"));
            info.setWind(jsonObjectWind.getString("speed"));
            info.setHumidity(jsonObjectMain.getString("humidity"));
            info.setPresure(jsonObjectMain.getString("pressure"));
            info.setDate(date);
                             } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }......}
    });
RequestQueue queue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
queue.add(objectRequest);
}
```

and the error as following

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"dt":1520380800,"main":{"temp":6.82,"temp_min":6.82,"temp_max":7.6,"pressure":1010.5,"sea_level":1030.48,"grnd_level":1010.5,"humidity":74,"temp_kf":-0.77},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02n"}],"clouds":{"all":24},"wind":{"speed":1.26,"deg":161.501},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2018-03-07 00:00:00"} at 2 of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

i have json code from openweathermap.org from postman as following :

```
{
"cod": "200",    "message": 0.0031,
"cnt": 40,
"list": [
    {
        "dt": 1520337600,
        "main": {
            "temp": 9.15,
            "temp_min": 9.15,
            "temp_max": 9.64,
            "pressure": 1032.25,
            "sea_level": 1041.73,
            "grnd_level": 1032.25,
            "humidity": 100,
            "temp_kf": -0.5
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 802,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "scattered clouds",
                "icon": "03n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 32
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 9.92,
            "deg": 55.5024
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2018-03-06 12:00:00"
    }, ......
```

where is the problem exactly ?? 
how can i solve this problem ??
 please help me and thank a lot ..

Answer (score 1):

Your problen is

```
JSONObject jsonObjectWeather=jsonArray.getJSONArray(2).getJSONObject(0);
```

jsonArray is the content of 'list' so if you want the weather you should do:

```
jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("weather").getJSONArray(0).getJSONObject(0);
```

Something like that.
But parsing a JSON manually is a pain in the a**.

Use Gson, it's gonna be far easier.

You define the object structure and then you do

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourRootClass res = gson.fromJson(json, YourRootClass.class);
```

*Magic*

Answer (score 0):

JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("list");

```
 JSONObject jsonObjectMain=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("weather")
```